# List of strings into Bson Array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using MongoDb 2.4.9 version. when i try to convert list of strings in to Bson Array i end up in below error:

```
BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
foreach (var term in termMonitorIds)
{
    bArray.Add(term.ToBson());
}
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: A String value cannot be written to the root level of a BSON document.

**EDIT**

When i use that in the LINQ Query below:

```
entities =
                    (from e in this.collection.AsQueryable<SocialRecord>()
                     where sources.Contains(e.SocialType) && (e.DateCreated >= fr) && (e.DateCreated <= to) && e.TermMonitorIds.Any(X=> bArray.Contains(X)) && e.IsExactMatch == isInstagramExactMatch
                     select e)
                    .Take(5000)
                    .ToList();
```

results in Value cannot be null. Parameter name: name . This error message only happens when i added bArray to the Query.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to invoke `ToBson`. There's already an implicit conversion from `string` to `BsonValue`. Using `ToBson` actually generates bson, which probably isn't your goal:

```
BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray();
foreach (var term in termMonitorIds)
{
    bArray.Add(term));
}
```

Comment: If you have a different question you should really make a new post.

Comment: You could make this a little more succinct by using: bArray.AddRange(termMonitorIds)

Comment: I've settled on: BsonArray bArray = new BsonArray(termMonitorIds);